# Writing `require` blocks rest of the code

Tags: php, database, pdo, require

Edit: As stated in comment section I removed try and catch statement to see the error and I was using the wrong database name. I was wondering am I suppose to remove the `try and catch` statement? Or just remove `die()` in catch and instead add some message such as `echo $e->getMessage();`?

In my php code whenever I write `require "database.php"` nothing works below that line. I am printing `echo` statement after `require` line, but it does not print. It's same if I have any code after that such as `for loop` or anything it won't print or go past the `require` line code. If I remove the `require` line everything works fine. What could be the reason for that?

My code:

```
<?php
//connecting to database
require "database.php";
echo 'after require code'; //this line won't print
// Errors on
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

database.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {

  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=root", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Most probably your code _dies_ when it reaches the `die();` after some `PDOException` occurs. Since you don't print any information about that error, you won't know what exact error happened. Remove the `try...catch` wrapper around `PDO` to allow the exception to show itself.

Comment: @Smuuf Thanks!! I accidently wrote `root` as database name rather actual database name. I was wondering shall I put back try and catch statement? Also, shall I write some print statement in catch block so I know if there is any error?

Comment: In dev or test environment you can add `var_dump($e);` before `die();` but not in production. In production exception should be writed into error log

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev So do you reckon to use error log as `echo $e->getMessage()`? Did you mean I need to still have `die()` after the error log?

Comment: Yes. If you have some logger class in your project add something like `$logger->error($e->getMessage());` and `die();` because rest of code going to be needless after DB connection error .

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev What do you mean by $logger? I didn't understand. Could you please explain? What class are you exactly talking about. All I have is index.php class at the moment.

Comment: @Sky, you can read https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/php-logging-basics/ for more information

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev you don't really need no tutorials for this. **PHP already logs all errors**, without any effort on your part (of course unless you deliberately turned it off).

Comment: Sky, so yes - you have to remove the try and catch statement, and also remove die(), and echo $e->getMessage(); **as well**. You see, PHP is not made by fools, so just *let PHP to do the job*. All your die and echo are only interfering.